# What is the best way to initialize python path?

Tags: python

## Problem description

Note that I didn't make my code to be something transferable as a module by installing on other computers.

I have several codes with several level of directory. Everytime I transfer to other computer, I do this following

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src/'))
```

## Question

What is the best way to add path in my python code in order to make it transferable easily?

Besides the above soultion, I know the following ways

1. make the **whole code** as a module that can be *python setup install* on any other computers
2. use environment variable, which I think is very ugly.

Comment: You seem to know two standard ways. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Are you asking for some kind of magic? Either you extend the `sys.path` to include your source files, or you put the source files under `sys.path`. _Either the mountain comes to Muhammad, or Muhammad goes to the mountain_.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mypython_file.py")
```